# pair wise AND operation between two set of elements

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, algorithms

I have two sets of size say $m$ and $n$. I wanted to find the sum of all pair-wise AND operation between the elements of both the sets.

Suppose, if set $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and set $B=\{8,9\}$. I want to get the value of $$1\&8 + 1\&9 + 2\&8 + 2\&9 + 3\&8 + 3\&9$$ where $\&$ is the bit-wise AND operation between the two numbers.

I am interested to know if there is a better solution than $O(mn)$ (or in other words "brute-force" method)??

Comment: Couldn't you OR all the bits within each set and then do one big AND operation between the sets?  That would be O(m+n) rather than a product.

Comment: I think $+$ here means arithmetic addition, not bitwise ‘or’, and that spoils your idea, but perhaps there's something I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If values are rather small (which could be especially true if we consider multi-sets), then you could optimize it by bit-counting.

Lets define
$$ f(X,Y) = [ f_0, f_1, ..., f_k ] $$
where $f_i = \# \{ x \in X : x \& 2^i = 1  \}$ (amount of numbers in $X$ that have $i'th$ bit set to $1$), and $k=\log_2(\min(\max(X),\max(Y)))$

This operation takes $O(nk)$ time, where $n=\#X$.

now it is quite easy to see, that answer to your question is given by

$$ f(A,B) \cdot f(B,A)$$

where $\cdot$ is a standard inner product.

So what we are actually doing, is counting for each bit how many times it appears in numbers in $A$ and in $B$, and then multiply them, so we get how many times $\&$ operation on the particular bit returned $1$, and then sum them up.

In your example
$$1 = 1\cdot2^0, 2=0\cdot2^0+1\cdot2^1,3=1\cdot2^0+1\cdot2^1$$
$$8=0\cdot2^0+0\cdot2^1+0\cdot2^2+1\cdot2^3, 9=1\cdot2^0+0\cdot2^1+0\cdot2^2+1\cdot2^3$$
$$f(A,B) = [2,1,0,0]$$
$$f(B,A) = [1,0,0,2]$$

$$f(A,B) \cdot f(B,A) = 2 = 1 \& 9 + 3 \& 9$$

as expected

The whole process takes $O(k(n+m))$ time, which is smaller then $O(mn)$ iff $k$ is small enough (if a bit length of the longest number in the sets is smaller then the amount of set's elements).

Comment: thanks for your answer..!!